# chkrootkit - Linux.Xor.DDoS installed

Tags: security

when I ran chkrootkit, it reported as below. How can I understand this? Is it system problem? or is it about chrome tabs ? or it s not problem ?

```
Searching for Linux.Xor.DDoS ...                            INFECTED: Possible Malicious Linux.Xor.DDoS installed
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.923O2s
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.yNrXnV
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.GWQuyN
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.ZqBAV0
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.cxfd6x
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.BKA8n9
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.ug99lV
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.qKYn2F
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.zTxN5P
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.6DPLBB
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.Xnftwc
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.3D5urW
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.MKRFq7
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.VyspzA
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.TtnRB0
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.9MGffU
/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.sZBSNR
```

Comment: I chose to install and run it (from Debian bullseye). It found my /tmp/foo.sh script which contains a single xrandr command generated by arandr and wrote "INFECTED: Possible Malicious Linux.Xor.DDoS installed" about it. So I guess it can do false positives. Can't tell if real positives can't be among false positives too.